# How to start a clickhouse container with testcontainers?

Tags: go

I'd like to use testcontainers for integration testing. I need to test against a clickhouse storage.

The docker image is [yandex/clichouse-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/yandex/clickhouse-server)

My code thus far (imported mostly from the official redis example on testcontainers website):

```
    ctx := context.Background()
    req := testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
        Image: "yandex/clickhouse-server",
        ExposedPorts: []string{"9000/tcp"},
    }
    chContainer, err := testcontainers.GenericContainer(ctx, testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
        ContainerRequest: req,
        Started:          true,
    })
    require.NoError(t, err, "unexpected error while creating clickhouse container")

    endpoint, err := chContainer.Endpoint(ctx, "")
    require.NoError(t, err)
```

This throws an error `port not found` on getting the endpoint, and I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the wait APIs in Testcontainers Go? https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/tree/main/wait

With them you'll be able to wait for multiple things (even at the same time):

- a log entry
- a port to be ready
- a SQL query
- an HTTP request
- an exit code after running a program in the container

You can find useful examples in the repository. I.e., and example for a log entry:

```golang
ctx := context.Background()
    req := ContainerRequest{
        Image:        "docker.io/mysql:latest",
        ExposedPorts: []string{"3306/tcp", "33060/tcp"},
        Env: map[string]string{
            "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD": "password",
            "MYSQL_DATABASE":      "database",
        },
        WaitingFor: wait.ForLog("test context timeout").WithStartupTimeout(1 * time.Second),
    }
    _, err := GenericContainer(ctx, GenericContainerRequest{
        ProviderType:     providerType,
        ContainerRequest: req,
        Started:          true,
    })
```

EDIT: a more elaborated example, including a wait strategy using HTTP requests would be:

```golang
const (
        dbName       = "crazy"
        fakeUser     = "jondoe"
        fakePassword = "bond girl"
    )

    ctx := context.Background()

    req := ContainerRequest{
        Image: "clickhouse/clickhouse-server",
        Env: map[string]string{
            "CLICKHOUSE_DB":       dbName,
            "CLICKHOUSE_USER":     fakeUser,
            "CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD": fakePassword,
        },
        ExposedPorts: []string{
            "8123/tcp",
            "9000/tcp",
        },
        WaitingFor: wait.ForAll(
            wait.ForHTTP("/ping").WithPort("8123/tcp").WithStatusCodeMatcher(
                func(status int) bool {
                    return status == http.StatusOK
                },
            ),
        ),
    }

    clickhouseContainer, err := GenericContainer(ctx, GenericContainerRequest{
        ContainerRequest: req,
        Started:          true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer clickhouseContainer.Terminate(ctx)
```

Comment: I would like to, in my solution I looped over a ping to the clickhouse to ensure it's up and running with a 10ms interval (or 10sec timeout). 
Maybe a log is triggered I could wait for ? That I don't know.

Comment: I haven't played with the clickhouse docker image yet, but I'm pretty sure they have an healthcheck or a log entry with "connections ready" or similar. You could try the wait.ForHTTP stragegy: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/blob/main/wait/http_test.go#L71

Comment: The java version waits for the http: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/master/modules/clickhouse/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/ClickHouseContainer.java#L57

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, there exists a ClickHouse module for testcontainers-go, since v0.23.0: https://golang.testcontainers.org/modules/clickhouse/

You could use it in a very simple manner:

Adding the dependency:

```bash
go get github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/modules/clickhouse
```

Import:

```golang
import "github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/modules/clickhouse"
```

Code:

```golang
ctx := context.Background()

user := "clickhouse"
password := "password"
dbname := "testdb"

clickHouseContainer, err := clickhouse.RunContainer(ctx,
    testcontainers.WithImage("clickhouse/clickhouse-server:23.3.8.21-alpine"),
    clickhouse.WithUsername(user),
    clickhouse.WithPassword(password),
    clickhouse.WithDatabase(dbname),
    clickhouse.WithInitScripts(filepath.Join("testdata", "init-db.sh")),
    clickhouse.WithConfigFile(filepath.Join("testdata", "config.xml")),
)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer func() {
    if err := clickHouseContainer.Terminate(ctx); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got working after trial / errors:

```
const (
    dbName       = "crazy"
    fakeUser     = "jondoe"
    fakePassword = "bond girl"
)

// NewTestClickhouseDB spins up a new clickhouse container database
func NewTestClickhouseDB(t *testing.T) *sql.DB {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    t.Cleanup(cancel)
    req := testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
        Image: "clickhouse/clickhouse-server",
        Env: map[string]string{
            "CLICKHOUSE_DB":       dbName,
            "CLICKHOUSE_USER":     fakeUser,
            "CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD": fakePassword,
        },

        ExposedPorts: []string{"9000/tcp"},
        WaitingFor:   wait.ForListeningPort("9000"),
    }
    chContainer, err := testcontainers.GenericContainer(ctx, testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
        ContainerRequest: req,
        Started:          true,
    })
    require.NoError(t, err, "unexpected error while creating clickhouse container")

    p, err := chContainer.MappedPort(ctx, "9000")
    require.NoError(t, err, "expected mapped port to be found on clickhouse container")

    addr := fmt.Sprintf("127.0.0.1:%d", p.Int())
    conn := clickhouse.OpenDB(&clickhouse.Options{
        Addr: []string{addr},
        Auth: clickhouse.Auth{
            Database: dbName,
            Username: fakeUser,
            Password: fakePassword,
        },
    })

    for {
        if ctx.Err() != nil {
            t.Fatalf("time/out: ping db failed for 10seconds")
        }
        err := conn.Ping()
        if err != nil {
            time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
            continue
        }
        break
    }

    return conn
}
```

This spins up a clickhouse container and returns the sql.Db or t/o after 10 seconds.